# Google ML Engine: Unable to save model

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm submitting a training job via the REST API. The process is able to train, but when it gets to the saving part it errors throwing a `The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1.` error. I've checked my IAM Permissions for the service account, and it has the following permissions:

- Logs Writer
- ML Engine Admin
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin

Here's a more in-depth traceback of the actual error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 223, in <module> dispatch(**parse_args.__dict__) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 133, in dispatch callbacks=callbacks) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1110, in fit_generator initial_epoch=initial_epoch) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1849, in fit_generator callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 63, in on_epoch_begin callback.on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 74, in on_epoch_begin copy_file_to_gcs(self.job_dir, checkpoints[-1]) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 150, in copy_file_to_gcs output_f.write(input_f.read()) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 126, in read pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 94, in _prepare_value return compat.as_str_any(val) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 106, in as_str_any return as_str(value) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 84, in as_text return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I'm not entirely sure as of why this is happening. The code is taken from the example projects on Googles git page. Nothing has been changed. Here's my REST call:

```
{
    "jobId": "training_20",
    "trainingInput": {
        "scaleTier": "BASIC",
        "packageUris": ["gs://MY_BUCKET/census.tar.gz"],
        "pythonModule": "trainer.task",
        "args": [
          "--train-files", 
          "gs://MY_BUCKET/adult.data.csv", 
          "--eval-files", 
          "gs://MY_BUCKET/adult.test.csv", 
          "--job-dir", 
          "gs://MY_BUCKET/models", 
          "--train-steps",
          "100",
          "--eval-steps",
          "10"],
        "region": "europe-west1",
        "jobDir": "gs://MY_BUCKET/models",
        "runtimeVersion": "1.4",
        "pythonVersion": "3.5"
    }
}
```

This is the saving code part:

```
# Unhappy hack to work around h5py not being able to write to GCS.
# Force snapshots and saves to local filesystem, then copy them over to GCS.
  if job_dir.startswith("gs://"):
    census_model.save(CENSUS_MODEL)
    copy_file_to_gcs(job_dir, CENSUS_MODEL)
  else:
    census_model.save(os.path.join(job_dir, CENSUS_MODEL))

  # Convert the Keras model to TensorFlow SavedModel
  model.to_savedmodel(census_model, os.path.join(job_dir, 'export'))

# h5py workaround: copy local models over to GCS if the job_dir is GCS.
def copy_file_to_gcs(job_dir, file_path):
  with file_io.FileIO(file_path, mode='r') as input_f:
    with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(job_dir, file_path), mode='w+') as output_f:
        output_f.write(input_f.read())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some further research, it seems to be a problem with how Google decided to save the file. Originally, it stated the type to be `r`: as seen here... `with file_io.FileIO(file_path, mode='r') as input_f:` . By changing the mode to be `rb` (binary) this solves the problem.

As the mode was set to `r` python tried to convert this byte-array (assumed it's utf-8) to a unicode string. Although, when it encounters a byte sequence `0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte` it doesn't follow the utf8 conventions, and thus crashes. A more indepth response is posted here by Alfe:

[error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in/42340744)