# How to provide encoding while reading multiple files?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading multiple csv files in from a folder. While reading multiple files I receive `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 21: invalid start byte`

When I try to read file one-by-one I provide encoding of type - `"ISO-8859-1"` in `pandas.read_csv(file_name, encoding`). My final objective is to append all files in single data frame. Following is the code I'm using for the mentioned purpose.

```
import glob


files = glob.glob('/path_name/*.csv')

df = None

for i, f in enumerate (files):
    if i == 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        df['fname'] = f
    else:
        tmp = read_csv(f)
        tmp['fname'] = f
        df = df.append(tmp)

df.head()
```

Comment: can't you use `"ISO-8859-1"` in all files ? or use `try/except` to catch error and read with different encoding.

Comment: I can; I tried  `df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding="ISO-8859-1")` but then it is not able to read files it generates `NameError: name 'read_csv' is not defined`

Comment: you get this error because you don't have function `read_csv()` - you should use `pd.read_csv()` inside `else`

Comment: I made edit to mentioned code while also importing the pandas

Comment: do you have own function `def read_csv():` ? Show it. Error shows that you don't have this function. I think you made small mistake in code and you forgot `pd.` in `else`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `errors='ignore'`, then everything works, but you will lose couple of characters.

```
with open(path, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
```

Comment: Could you please share the full code, I don't where I should add it. I will accept if it works

Comment: Sure! Please check this link for detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in/42340744