# Django saving image from URL to model causes UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: django, file, model

I have simple model with overrided save() method, I want to save image from given url, every time save mehod is called.

Here is my code:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    # Creating URL to request
    URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&key=" + settings.KEY
    URL += "&photoreference=" + self.reference

    result = urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL)
    self.image_file.save(
            os.path.basename(self.reference),
            File(open(result[0]))
    )
    self.save()
```

And this throws this error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/fest_strona/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('app.urls')),
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.views import *
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    import app.scripts_for_api_control.main as SFAC
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/scripts_for_api_control/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    places_info.get_place_photo_by_reference("CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU")
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/scripts_for_api_control/high_level_code.py", line 110, in get_place_photo_by_reference
    image = low_level_code.get_image_from_URL_and_save_to_DB(photo_reference)
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/scripts_for_api_control/low_level_code.py", line 55, in get_image_from_URL_and_save_to_DB
    to_save_image_instance.save()
  File "/home/dolidod/coding/fest-apka/app/models.py", line 26, in save
    File(open(result[0]))
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 87, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 52, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 270, in _save
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 60, in chunks
    data = self.read(chunk_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I found possible solution with addding:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
  contents = f.read()
```

But, now my question is: How can I use this piece of code to handle saving image in my save() function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)

Comment: Downvoted because simply writing *"I'm getting this error"* is less than helpful for anyone. Please include the complete traceback. Anyway, this error is caused when you try to read binary data as unicode data (which Python does by default). Hence, you need to pass `'rb'` to the `open` function. The `b` tells python to read the data as binary.

Comment: @xyres I eddited my answer, I think its more clear now.

Comment: Im still confused how this is not a duplicate it literally has the exact same title. Why is this my flag not getting accepted?

Comment: @AgentLu This question is based on python. And i don't know how to implement this code in my django model - thats the difference

Comment: @DolidodTeethtard Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
File(open(result[0], 'rb'))
```

Comment: because he will open and read as byte i guess, idk it worked to me