# How to remove "double quotes" in data, when reading data with the read_csv method?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm reading data from a .csv file using pandas.
I'm using **sep = ', \ s *'**  because **sep = ','**  not working to specify columns.
My **.csv file** :

```
tarih_x,Alt_urun,per_geomean
2018-07-13,Antep fıstığı-Açık,81.87336164596796
2018-07-14,Antep fıstığı-Açık,81.87336164596796
2018-07-15,Antep fıstığı-Açık,81.87336164596796
2018-07-16,Antep fıstığı-Açık,81.87336164596796
2018-07-17,Antep fıstığı-Açık,81.87336164596796
```

I'm reading data:

```py
path = "data//gün_result_index.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path,encoding='utf-16',sep=',\s*',engine='python')
```

but when I print df, I see that the method adds double quotes to the data:

```
|   | "tarih_x    | Alt_urun           | per_geomean"       |
|---|-------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| 0 | "2018-07-13 | Antep fıstığı-Açık | 81.87336164596796" |
| 1 | "2018-07-14 | Antep fıstığı-Açık | 81.87336164596796" |
| 2 | "2018-07-15 | Antep fıstığı-Açık | 81.87336164596796" |
| 3 | "2018-07-16 | Antep fıstığı-Açık | 81.87336164596796" |
```

This is not something I want. How can I read data without double quotes?

Comment: Maybe try `pd.read_csv(path, encoding='itf-16', sep=',\s*', quotechar='"', engine='python')`

Comment: I think this might be problem with encodings, which was tampered with when you copy&pasted the file content here. Can you please share the original file as base64?

Comment: @Erfan Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: @Ente data here: https://postamuedu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/birdalugureren_posta_mu_edu_tr/ERD-L_RKZbZDmV9sKdfEd1YBDG8h5D573GuNDdB1IfngXQ?rtime=h5pxhEpV10g

Comment: @UğurEren: That's an excel spreadsheet and does not help. Sorry. Please provide the original `.csv` file, preferably as base64 encoded. Here on the page.

Comment: When I opened the file with notepad, I saw quotation marks.i found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For me `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')` works just fine:

```
      tarih_x            Alt_urun  per_geomean
0  2018-07-13  Antep fıstığı-Açık    81.873362
1  2018-07-14  Antep fıstığı-Açık    81.873362
2  2018-07-15  Antep fıstığı-Açık    81.873362
3  2018-07-16  Antep fıstığı-Açık    81.873362
4  2018-07-17  Antep fıstığı-Açık    81.873362
```

But `encoding='utf-16'` gives:
`UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`

I use pandas 0.25.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: This gives an error like this:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Try `encoding=latin1`, I know it is not for Turkish alphabet. Also try to read csv line by line to detect problematic line, I think that file could be corrupted.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in

Comment: I got values ​​filled with NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a shorter way.
The workaround I found is:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\"', '')
for i in df.columns:
    df[i]= df[i].apply(lambda x: x.replace("\"",""))
```