# I am facing an error while i try to load a file in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open(path,'r',encoding='utf8')
```

This is the code I'm trying to run but it outputs `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte` as the error. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Maybe your file isn't utf8-encoded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)

Comment: Did you check the encoding of your file in `path`?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yes, the link you provided helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your encoding to utf-8, and see if that fixes it. Otherwise, the file might not be encoded in utf-8.