# pd.read_excel throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pandas, file

I am trying to read data from excel to pandas. The file I get comes from api and is not saved (the access to the file needs special permissions, so I don't want to save it). When I try to read excel from file

> ```
> with open('path_to_file') as file:
>     re = pd.read_excel(file)
> ```

I get the error

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
> 10: invalid start byte
> ```

When I input path in palce of file everythng works fine

> ```
> re = pd.read_excel('path-to-exactly-the-same-file')
> ```

Is there a way to read excel by pandas without saving it and inputting path?

Comment: Try to read the file as bytes: `with open('path_to_file', 'rb') as file`

Answer (score 2):

the part that was missing was  `'rb'` in open

```
with open('path_to_file', 'rb') as file:
    re = pd.read_excel(file)
```

to treat the file as binary. Idea taken from [error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)