# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8, while converting sql dump to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I am using a python script from [here](https://github.com/yashsmehta/mysqldump-to-csv/blob/master/mysqldump_to_csv.py) to convert a gzipped large sql dump into CSV. It works perfectly until it reaches a specific line after the text `47896122,1,'Brigadier_General_Albert_Pike',3`. After this line it encounter some kind of Byte `0xf8` which can not be decoded by python.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
import csv
import sys

# This prevents prematurely closed pipes from raising
# an exception in Python
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)

# allow large content in the dump
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

def is_insert(line):
    """
    Returns true if the line begins a SQL insert statement.
    """
    return line.startswith('INSERT INTO') or False


def get_values(line):
    """
    Returns the portion of an INSERT statement containing values
    """
    return line.partition('` VALUES ')[2]


def values_sanity_check(values):
    """
    Ensures that values from the INSERT statement meet basic checks.
    """
    assert values
    assert values[0] == '('
    # Assertions have not been raised
    return True


def parse_values(values, outfile):
    """
    Given a file handle and the raw values from a MySQL INSERT
    statement, write the equivalent CSV to the file
    """
    latest_row = []

    reader = csv.reader([values], delimiter=',',
                        doublequote=False,
                        escapechar='\\',
                        quotechar="'",
                        strict=True
    )

    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for reader_row in reader:
        for column in reader_row:
            # If our current string is empty...
            if len(column) == 0 or column == 'NULL':
                latest_row.append(chr(0))
                continue
            # If our string starts with an open paren
            if column[0] == "(":
                # Assume that this column does not begin
                # a new row.
                new_row = False
                # If we've been filling out a row
                if len(latest_row) > 0:
                    # Check if the previous entry ended in
                    # a close paren. If so, the row we've
                    # been filling out has been COMPLETED
                    # as:
                    #    1) the previous entry ended in a )
                    #    2) the current entry starts with a (
                    if latest_row[-1][-1] == ")":
                        # Remove the close paren.
                        latest_row[-1] = latest_row[-1][:-1]
                        new_row = True
                # If we've found a new row, write it out
                # and begin our new one
                if new_row:
                    writer.writerow(latest_row)
                    latest_row = []
                # If we're beginning a new row, eliminate the
                # opening parentheses.
                if len(latest_row) == 0:
                    column = column[1:]
            # Add our column to the row we're working on.
            latest_row.append(column)
        # At the end of an INSERT statement, we'll
        # have the semicolon.
        # Make sure to remove the semicolon and
        # the close paren.
        if latest_row[-1][-2:] == ");":
            latest_row[-1] = latest_row[-1][:-2]
            writer.writerow(latest_row)


def main():
    """
    Parse arguments and start the program
    """
    # Iterate over all lines in all files
    # listed in sys.argv[1:]
    # or stdin if no args given.
    try:
        for line in fileinput.input():
            # Look for an INSERT statement and parse it.
            if is_insert(line):
                values = get_values(line)
                if values_sanity_check(values):
                    parse_values(values, sys.stdout)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the [link to the input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7sOjCViSVVqww33bM0x6XuAH6HZs3Ok/view?usp=sharing)

Here is how to run the code until error:
`python3 mysqldump_to_csv.py input.sql > output.csv`

Now I have three questions:

1. How can I view the exact byte to understand what is causing all this problem? I want to understand what is byte `0xf8` and where it is residing in the input file.
2. Is there any way I can convert this erroneous byte to something that is readable? I am asking this because when I open the [raw input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7sOjCViSVVqww33bM0x6XuAH6HZs3Ok/view?usp=sharing) in sublime text, sublime text is not complaining in showing the characters in the file and sublime text is set to UTF-8 encoding.
3. If it is not at all possible to decode those bytes without ignoring, how do I ignore them in python `fileinput` module in the code I provided? I  understand it is possible to ignore errors in `utf-8` encoding using something like `with open(path, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:`
   based on answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in/42340744) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c) stackoverflow questions, but I really need to use `fileinput` module because it helps me to grab lines from standard input, as I am using gzcat to provide input from a huge compressed sql file to this python program.

Comment: That's *not* the raw input file.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the third question asked here, one can add encoding argument in the `fileinput.input` function like the following:

`fileinput.input(openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8",errors="ignore"))`.