# Installing pylint with PyCharm

Tags: pylint

I tried to install pylint with the pylint plugin in PyCharm.

I created a blank project in a venv.

I am using:

```
pylint 2.14.0
astroid 2.11.5
Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
PyCharm 2022.1.2
```

I tried:

- specifying the path of the exe explicitly in the plugin-setting (C:\git\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\pylint.exe)
- different Python version (3.9.6)
- different pylint version
- new venv
- reinstall pylint plugin
- Re-installing PyCharm
- Restart PC

I get the following Error, when i try to run -help in the console

```
> (venv) PS C:\git\pythonProject1> pylint -help

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwmAY.png)

Has anyone a clue? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, please take a look at these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s

Comment: @Hamed_gibago Thanks I already looked at those. However I dont want to change the encoding, since UTF-8 is the standard.

Comment: Do you have any of the files listed in the link below that pylint treats as possible configuration files which is not UTF-8 encoded?

https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html?highlight=pylintrc#command-line-options

Comment: if I don't have the rcfile, and I enter pylint -help in the terminal, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

need to use

```
pip install pylint
```

then generate a pylintrc file like:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

and move it into your projects folder

then find the path to pylint for example:

```
venv/bin/pylint
```

then go to preferences ->  pylint in PyCharm and set the pylint executable to be that path and click test

Note i have found the SonarLint plugin easier to work with. I wasn't seeing a way to navigate from the lint error to the setting to turn off the link but i saw that with SonarLint