# Unable to open .csv file using pandas (downloaded from outlook); 'utf-8' codec error

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, outlook, character-encoding

I'm trying to download and save a .csv file I receive daily in my outlook inbox.
The code saves the file in the a local folder.
When I try to access it using pandas, I get a 'utf-8' codec error

```
import os
from enum import Enum
import win32com.client as win32
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

class OutlookFolder(Enum):
    olFolderInbox = 6

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(OutlookFolder.olFolderInbox.value)

messages = inbox.Items
messages = messages.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = ABCD@XYZ.com")

t = datetime.today().date()

outputDir = r"C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\ABCD\Daily Seed File"
try:
    for message in list(messages):
        if message.ReceivedTime.date() == t:
            try:
                s = message.sender
                for attachment in message.Attachments:
                    fn = attachment.FileName[:-4] + "_" + str(message.ReceivedTime.date()) + ".csv"
                    attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(outputDir,fn))
                    print(f"attachment {attachment.FileName} from {s} saved")
            except Exception as e:
                print("error when saving the attachment:" + str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("error when processing email messages:" + str(e))

fp = outputDir + "\\" + fn

df = pd.read_csv(fp)
df.head()
```

I'm getting the following error -

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)

Comment: That means the file is *NOT* a UTF8 file. It may be UTF8 with a BOM, or UTF16. Try loading it with `encoding='utf-8-sig'` or `encoding='utf-16'`

Comment: @Paul that's not a helpful question. Pandas already tried using UTF8, so the accepted answer isn't useful. Ignoring errors isn't useful either, so the second is wrong. And this is definitely not Latin1, which means the 3rd is wrong too. It's quite likely this is a UTF16 LE file with a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which *does* start with 0xFF.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, using ```encoding='utf-16'``` helped but the it is combining all the columns into one and all rows into a binary output - 0/1. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `binary output` mean? UTF16 is just text. Have you tried opening that file? What's the column separator? Is it `;` or a tab perhaps?

Comment: Is that file an actual CSV file? Your code is stripping the extension and appending `.csv`. Perhaps it's an Excel file or a ZIP file. What does `attachment.FileName` contain? At the very least preserve the original extension instead of replacing it

Comment: I added another arg to ```pandas.read_csv()``` namely ```sep="\t"``` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `encoding` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fp, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: The error complains that the file is *NOT* a valid UTF8 file. `read_csv` already used `utf8`. 0xFF isn't valid in UTF8

Comment: Specifying encoding='utf-8' didn't help. Pandas is already using utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

The file had a UTF-16 encoding and tab or `\t` separator.
The following works -

```
df = pd.read_csv(fp, encoding ='utf-16', sep="\t")
```