# File <frozen codecs>, line 322, in decode UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, command-line, streamlit

Writing a python file app.py and running it using streamlit in the environment, i keep getting this error when i run app.py using the command:
`streamlit run app.py`

app.py code:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from os import path
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie

st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Project Recommender System",
    page_icon=":tada:",
    layout="wide",
)

# --function to access json data from animation file --
def load_lottieurl(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code!=200:
        return None
    return r.json()


lottie_coding="https://lottie.host/?file=27f9afaf-6b4d-4b82-9ddd-0090383cc539/uiGM12Tq9s.json"
img_contact_form = Image.open("images/project-contact-form.png")
img_lottie_animation=Image.open("images/stock-price-prediction-web-app.png")

with st.container():
    st.subheader("AcademiaLink's Project Recommender System")
    st.title("A recommender system for projects of your choice")

# -- Opens Home page --
# st.write("[Explore AcademiaLink >]()")

with right_column:
    st_lottie(lottie_coding, height=300, key="coding")
    
    
with st.container():
    st.header("Project Recommendations")
    st.write("---")
    image_col, text_col=st.columns((1,2))
    with image_col:
        st.image(img_lottie_animation)
    with text_col:
        st.subheader("Sales Forecasting using ARIMA")
        st.write(
    """This is a machine learning project which performs exploratory data analysis on sales forecasting using ARIMA. The dataset used in the project is acquired from Kaggle and since the data proves to be seasonal, we use SARIMAX class model to derive apt and accurate predictions for the next 36 months.
    """
        )
        st.markdown("[Explore the project](https://github.com/vindhya1103/Sales-Forecasting-using-ARIMA)")
        
with st.container():
    image_col, text_col = st.columns((1,2))
    with image_col:
        st.image(img_contact_form)
    with text_col:
        st.subheader("")
        st.write()
        st.markdown("[Explore the project]()")
```

Output in command line after the command streamlit run app.py:

```
C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\toolswebapp>streamlit run app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\streamlit\web\cli.py", line 201, in main_run
    bootstrap.load_config_options(flag_options=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\streamlit\web\bootstrap.py", line 367, in load_config_options
    config.get_config_options(force_reparse=True, options_from_flags=options_from_flags)
  File "C:\Users\Vindhya Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\streamlit\config.py", line 1229, in get_config_options
    file_contents = input.read()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I also tried running the command as administrator and made some changes with the encoding and some page icons. Changed all utf-8 encoding and installed tensorflow using pip. I expected an output giving me the local host web URLs. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)

Comment: The line "with st.container():" is the code for container but this question opens the file     " with open(path, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:  "

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error while working on streamlit.
To solve this, you have to change the enocoding of config.toml to UTF-8:

- go to File Explorer
  and search for config.toml
- open the config file with Notepad and change encoding to UTF-8 and save.

[image: IMAGE of utf-8 changing]